# Login to Opencart's admin with curl of PHP

Tags: php, curl, opencart, simple-html-dom

I want to login to OpenCart CMS with curl automatically and add things to it automatic too
but I can't login to it.I searched and found some result but couldn't help me and I don't get any result. This is my code:

```
<?php
include_once "simple_html_dom.php";
$username = 'active';
$password = '123active';
$loginUrl = 'http://localhost:100/mywebsite/admin/';

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginUrl);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'username='.$username.'&password='.$password);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$store = curl_exec($ch);
$html=new simple_html_dom();
$html->load($store);
foreach($html->find("li#dashboard") as $dash){
    echo $dash->innertext;
}
?>
```

In this code first I initialize `username` and `password` and my URL of linking to 
 to admin of my website then I use `CURLOPT_POST` request and `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`  
 and then execute the `$ch` but now I don't have any result on `cookie.txt` and didn't 
 login to website's admin.

Comment: Is it problem with `&autologin=1&userlogi=login`?.I test!but don't get result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at http://demo.opencart.com/admin/ and saw that the action url in the form is not only /admin. Try this one:

```
<?php
include_once "simple_html_dom.php";
$username = 'active';

$password = '123active';
//$loginUrl = 'http://localhost:100/mywebsite/admin/';
//new url
$loginUrl = 'http://localhost:100/mywebsite/admin/index.php?route=common/login';

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginUrl);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );

// follows a location header redirect
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'username='.$username.'&password='.$password);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$store = curl_exec($ch);
$html=new simple_html_dom();
$html->load($store);
foreach($html->find("li#dashboard") as $dash){
    echo $dash->innertext;
}
?>
```

I didnt't test if the action url depends on a specific version, so just inspect the form with your browser developer tools

Comment: I want to add product automatically from text to OpenCart do you hace any suggest?

Comment: My suggestion is, to look for an OpenCart API, I'm not really into OpenCart but I think there are some API extension maybe there is a built in API. Maybe this helps: (http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=15445&filter_search=rest%20api&filter_license=0)

Comment: I want some problem with `cookie.txt` and I cannot fill it! I do some search but don't get any result.I want to know why I don't get any result in this file?May I have problem with cookies?please read the code in cookie section

Comment: This seems to be a permission problem, you can check it if you try this `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, '/tmp/cookie.txt');

$store = curl_exec($ch);
$cookieContent = file_get_contents( dirname(__FILE__).'/tmp/cookie.txt' );
var_dump( $cookieContent );`   ...by the way /tmp/ is not the place where a cookie should be saved ;)

Comment: I want to access to some pages in catalog menu in opencart admin but when I want to echo that options for example product name in the list of products it show me the login page and when i login it show me the hole of page! what's wrong?any ideas my friend?link of code [link](http://s6.picofile.com/file/8210205342/index.php.html)

Comment: the problem is, that for security reasons open card uses tokens, so I really recommend you that you are using an OpenCart API, or if you really want to write your own, it doesn't make sense, that you do that only with curl without the context of OpenCart.

Comment: OH!Thanks my friend! All of problem was by cookie! but What ??May you explain me?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88802/discussion-between-meer-and-swidmann).

Comment: in the post above this `file_get_contents( dirname(__FILE__).'/tmp/cookie.txt' );`should mean `file_get_contents('/tmp/cookie.txt' );` just without the `dirname(__FILE__).`